# Remove text line in XML file C# .NET

Tags: c#, xml, text, replace

i need to write app to remove specific text line in very large XML file (about 3,5 GB).

I wrote this code:

```
    string directoryPath;

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
            textBox2.Text = directoryPath;
            textBox1.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;
        }
    }

    private void Replace()
    {
        StreamReader readerFile = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        while (!readerFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            string stringReplaced;
            string replaceResult = textBox2.Text + "\\" + "replace_results";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(replaceResult);
            StreamWriter writerFile = new StreamWriter(replaceResult + "\\" + textBox1.Text, true);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            char[] buff = new char[10 * 1024 * 1024];
            int xx = readerFile.ReadBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            sb.Append(buff);
            stringReplaced = sb.ToString();
            stringReplaced = stringReplaced.Replace("line to remove", string.Empty);
            writerFile.WriteLine(stringReplaced);
            writerFile.Close();
            writerFile.Dispose();
            stringReplaced = null;
            sb = null;
        }


        readerFile.Close();
        readerFile.Dispose();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Replacing in progress...";
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Replace();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Replacing complete!";
        }
        catch
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Error! Replacing aborted!";
        }
    }
}
```

it works, but not as well because new file (after remove lines) is bigger than original file and at the end of new file are added some junk (lots of dots), screenshot:

https://images81.fotosik.pl/615/873833aa0e23b36f.jpg

How i can fix my code to make new file the same as old file, only without specific lines?

Answer (score 0):

For a start why keep opening and closing the output file? Keep it open.

Secondly reading blocks – which could lead to "line to remove" being split across blocks – and writing lines is an odd mix.

But I expect your issue is three fold:

1. You do not set the encoding of the output file.
2. When you read the buffer (10MB) you may get fewer characters read – the return from `ReadBlock`. But you always write the complete block. Limit the write to match the amount read (as updated but the replace).
3. `ReadBlock` will include end of lines, but `WriteLine` will add them: either work on blocks or on lines. Mixing will only create problems (and avoid the second issue above).

This leads to code something like:

```
using (var rdr = OpenReadFile(...))
using (var wtr = OpenWriteFile(...)) {
  string line;
  while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    line = line.Replace(x, y);
     str.WriteLine(line);
  }
}
```

**NB** Processing XML as text could lead to corrupting the XML (there is no such thing as "invalid XML": either the document is valid XML or it isn't XML, just something that looks a bit like it might be XML). Therefore any such approach needs to be handled with caution. The "proper" answer is to process as XML with the streaming APIs (`XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`) to avoid parsing the whole document as one.

Comment: How can i do this work only on lines without out of memory exception? Can you give me the code? :)

Comment: @gos: The central loop should be: read line, process, write line. You'll only have one line at a time in memory.

Comment: @gos: See expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

I trying do this by XmlTextReader but i have system.xml.xmlexception during read my file, screenshot: https://images82.fotosik.pl/622/d98b35587b0befa4.jpg

Code:

```
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(ofd.FileName);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlReader);
```